# svg path is not drawn if it's exacly horizontal (eg. y always zero)

Tags: svg

It appears as if an svg path is not being drawn, if it's y-points are nothing but 0 (eg. a straight horizontal line).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -150 1200 300" width="1200" height="300">
<defs><linearGradient id="line">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="6.25%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="18.75%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="31.25%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="43.75%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="56.25%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="68.75%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="81.25%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="93.75%" stop-color="#fcb404"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1c83d4"></stop>
</linearGradient></defs>

<path d="M0 -52 l75 0 l150 0 l150 0 l150 1 l150 0 l150 0 l150 0 l150 0 l75 0" stroke="url(#line)" fill="none" stroke-width="2px"></path>
</svg>
```

It "has to be" a path (usually it's not a straight line).
Has anyone experienced the same and perhaps knows where this behaviour comes from - and how to solve the "invisibility" problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not being drawn by which SVG renderer(s)? Just one? Or all of them?

Comment: No svg renders, if all y-values are 0 - and (since this question is indeed a copy) a Gradient is defined.
Thanks @robert-longson!